# Hibernate save object (one to many relationship) foreign key is null

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jakarta-ee, http-post

I have one to many relationships between person class and car class. A person can own many cars and vice versa. I am using restful API to post data. My annotations and Get service is working fine but my post service throws " `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL" error` whenever I try to insert new data. Child table `foreign key` is being inserted as `null`.

Here is part of my code.

Person.java

```
 private List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="person")    
@JsonManagedReference
public List<Car> getCars() {
  return cars;
 }
```

Car.java

```
private Person person;  

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID", nullable = false, updatable = true, insertable = true)
    @JsonBackReference
    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }
```

My service class:

```
@POST
        @Path("/PersonRegistration")
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response postPersonCars(Person person) throws Exception{

            Session session = null;     
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();   
            //Person per = new Person();
            //Car cars = new Car();
            try{
                session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                session.beginTransaction(); 
                //per.setCars(person.getCars());
                session.save(person);
                session.getTransaction().commit();

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw e;
            }finally{
                if(null != session){
                    session.close();
                }
            }

            return Response.status(201).entity(mapper.writeValueAsString(person)).build();
        }
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This annotation:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="person")
```

has two consequences:

1. `mappedBy` implies that `Car` is the owning side of the relationship. This means that whenever you want to establish a relationship between `Car` and `Person`, **you need to do it by setting the `Car.person` property to the appropriate value**. Changes to `Person.cars` will be ignored by Hibernate.
2. `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` means that whenever you save a `Person`, Hibernate will also invoke the save operation on all entities contained in `Person.cars`

Result: you are calling `Session.save()` on a bunch of `Car` entities that do not have the `Car.person` property set properly.

Solution: either change the owning side of the relationship (be aware that you will also need a `@JoinColumn` on `Person.cars` if you do not want an extra database table to be created) or loop through `Person.cars` and set the `Car.person` property properly in each of them.

`cascade=CascadeType.ALL` suggests the first solution fits your use case better.

Comment: Thanks crizzis for your answer. I am calling session.save on person entity that has ArrayList of cars. So should I iterate the json and set cars to Person ?

Comment: You should iterate over `person.getCars()` and call `car.setPerson(person)` on each `car`

Comment: So for deleting too I need do the same ? iterate over person.getCars and delete car and then person? Is this good approach or am I missing anything ?

Comment: No. Deleting the person should be enough in this case as `CascadeType.ALL` will cascade the deletion