# JPARepository is not saving @JoinColumn

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following Entity Relations:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
@Entity
public class BatchProcessRecord implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "batch_process_id")
    private BatchProcess batchProcess;
}


@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
@Entity
public class BatchProcess implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "batchProcess")
    private List<BatchProcessRecord> records;
}
```

And the following code that saves the entities:

```
    // Create batch process
    BatchProcess batchProcess = BatchProcess.builder()
            ....
            .records(records)
            .build();

    // Save entity
    batchProcessRepository.save(batchProcess);
```

In the console, it generates the inserts as expected (with 2 children), but without filling `batch_process_id` (JoinColumn).

What is happening?

Console:

```
Hibernate: insert into batch_process (batch_end_date, batch_entries_count, batch_entries_with_issues, batch_name, batch_start_date, report_file_download_date, report_file_name, result_file_name, result_file_upload_date, status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into batch_process_record (address_number, batch_process_id, city, first_name, full_street_address, last_name, maternal_name, post_directional, pre_directional, reference_number, ssn, state, street_type, zip_code) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into batch_process_record (address_number, batch_process_id, city, first_name, full_street_address, last_name, maternal_name, post_directional, pre_directional, reference_number, ssn, state, street_type, zip_code) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2
```

Repository:

```
public interface BatchProcessRepository extends 
JpaRepository<BatchProcess, Long> {
}
```

Comment: Are you setting `batchProcess` to all the records as well? Like, by calling `BatchProcessRecord.setBatchProcess()`...

Comment: No, do I need to do it? I thought that setting was automatically done by JPA

Comment: Yes, you need to do that. Otherwise, they will have `null`.

Comment: It works!!!. But I though that  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) would take care of that!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate save object (one to many relationship) foreign key is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41368301/hibernate-save-object-one-to-many-relationship-foreign-key-is-null)