# JPA inserting foreign key as null

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Well, I have tried every thing I could find online and still no luck.

I have 2 classes. TrendsChart & Trends. It's OneToManyMapping. TrendsChart can have multiple Trends.

DB : SQL Server

*TrendsChart Table*

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TrendsChart](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Name] [varchar] (50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

*Trends Table*

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Trends](
    [TrendsID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
        [ItemName] [varchar] (100) NULL,
    [chart_id] [int] NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [TrendsID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Trends]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Trends_TrendsChart] FOREIGN KEY([chart_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TrendsChart] ([id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Trends] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Trends_TrendsChart]
GO
```

*TrendsChart Model*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TrendsChart")
public class TrendsChart {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="Name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="trendsChart", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Trends> trends = new ArrayList<>();
```

*Trends Model*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Trends")
public class Trends {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="TrendsID")
    private int trendsID;

    @Column(name="ItemName")
    private String itemName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name ="chart_id", nullable=false, updatable = false, insertable = true,referencedColumnName = "id")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private TrendsChart trendsChart;
```

In the controller I am doing

```
trendsChartRepository.save(trendsChart);
```

All the data is being populated correctly except *chart_id* column which is always null

Comment: This is essentially the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41368301/hibernate-save-object-one-to-many-relationship-foreign-key-is-null), the only difference is that `chart_id` accepts `NULL`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate save object (one to many relationship) foreign key is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41368301/hibernate-save-object-one-to-many-relationship-foreign-key-is-null)

Answer (score 0):

You have to actively set each trend for the TrandChart:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TrendsChart")
public class TrendsChart {

   //...

   public void addTrend(Trends trend) {
      this.trends.add(trend);
      trend.setTrendsChart(this);
   }

}
```

And then for saving:

```
TrendsChart trendsChart = new TrendsChart();
Trends trend = new Trend();
trendsChart.setTrend(trend);
trendsChartRepository.save(trendsChart);
```

Here is a good tutorial on this topic:
https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/