# Saving entity in jpa with one to many relationship get this errors bellow

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Service:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public ContactDTO save(ContactDTO contactDTO) {
    Contact contact = new Contact();
    modelMapper.map(contactDTO.getIdentification(), contact);
    contact.setAddresses(contactDTO
            .getAddressList().stream().map(s ->
            {
                Address address = new Address();
                modelMapper.map(s, address);
                return address;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList()));

    repository.save(contact);
    return contactDTO;
}
```

Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contract")
public class Contact {
    ... 
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "contact", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address implements Serializable {

    ....

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="contact_id", nullable=false)
    private Contact contact;
}
```

Error Logs:

```
2020-09-02 14:09:44.939 ERROR 20148 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : NULL not allowed for column "CONTACT_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into address (city, contact_id, number, state, street, type, unit, zipcode, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-197]
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41368301/hibernate-save-object-one-to-many-relationship-foreign-key-is-null/41368850

Comment: `@Table(name = "contract")` I did remember to correct this to **contact** this might be a mistake why it did not run.

Answer (score 2):

You need to sync both sides in bi-directional relationship, means you need to set `Contract` in every `Address` to update the foreign key

```
contact.getAddresses().forEach(a -> a.setContact(contact));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply will try this if it will work.

Comment: Hi this error cause to have a stockoverflow error because it will loop adding the contract

Comment: @JoseMarlonAncajas when you get `stockoverflow error` ? when get or return ?

Comment: when invoking the post request.

Comment: I am not really sure what happened just corrected my code base on @Marc link giving above.

Comment: `it will loop adding the contract ` I didn't understand that, set contract should not cause StackOverflow.

Comment: yes, I was trying to understand it also. but when I add `address.setContact(contact);` as mention of course you need to make it final the contract to be accessed in the stream as I run it, it throws the stockoverflow error.

Comment: I don't know what problem happening you can try sperately like `contact.getAddresses().forEach(a -> a.setContact(contact));` I update my answer  also

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by changing my code.

From:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name="contact_id", nullable=false)
private Contact contact;
```

To:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinColumn(name="contact_id")
private Contact contact;
```

**removed the nullable=false and change CascadeType.REFRESH**