# composite key cascade set null spring jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, composite-key

I have two entity connecting with One-to-many relationships

the child has a composite key

when I try to insert in the child through parent using cascade

return null exception

iam using spring jpa ,hibernate,springboot

parent

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="ITEM"
    ,schema="MGITCLOTHES2020"
    , uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="CODE_COMPANY"), @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="NAME")} 
)
public class Item implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id    
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ITEM_ID_GENERATOR", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "SEQ_ITEM")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ITEM_ID_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "item", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ItemUnit> itemUnits = new ArrayList<ItemUnit>(0);

    public Item() {
    }
```

child

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM_UNIT",
         schema = "MGITCLOTHES2020"
)
public class ItemUnit implements java.io.Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "unitId", column = @Column(name = "UNIT_ID", nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "itemId", column = @Column(name = "ITEM_ID", nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0))})
    private ItemUnitId id;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Item item;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "UNIT_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Unit unit;

    public ItemUnit() {
    }
```

this composite key I am using Embedded id

```
@Embeddable
public class ItemUnitId  implements java.io.Serializable {
     @Column(name="UNIT_ID", nullable=false, precision=22, scale=0)
     private Long unitId;
     @Column(name="ITEM_ID", nullable=false, precision=22, scale=0)
     private Long itemId;

    public ItemUnitId() {
    }
        
   public boolean equals(Object other) {
         if ( (this == other ) ) return true;
         if ( (other == null ) ) return false;
         if ( !(other instanceof ItemUnitId) ) return false;
         ItemUnitId castOther = ( ItemUnitId ) other; 
         
         return ( (this.getUnitId()==castOther.getUnitId()) || ( this.getUnitId()!=null && castOther.getUnitId()!=null && this.getUnitId().equals(castOther.getUnitId()) ) )
 && ( (this.getItemId()==castOther.getItemId()) || ( this.getItemId()!=null && castOther.getItemId()!=null && this.getItemId().equals(castOther.getItemId()) ) );
   }
   
   public int hashCode() {
         int result = 17;
         
         result = 37 * result + ( getUnitId() == null ? 0 : this.getUnitId().hashCode() );
         result = 37 * result + ( getItemId() == null ? 0 : this.getItemId().hashCode() );
         return result;
   }   
}
```

the error message is
oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-01400: ?? ???? ????? NULL ??("MGITCLOTHES2020"."ITEM_UNIT"."ITEM_ID")
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:513) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:461) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1104) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hibernate save object (one to many relationship) foreign key is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41368301/hibernate-save-object-one-to-many-relationship-foreign-key-is-null)

Comment: it still return null
oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-01400:  NULL ??  ("MGITCLOTHES2020"."ITEM_UNIT"."ITEM_ID")